# how to change the color of certain pixels in bitmap android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

i've a bitmap that i want to change certain pixels. i've got the data from the bitmap into an array, but how would i set a pixels colour in that array?

thanks

```
int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
            myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

            for(int i =0; i<500;i++){
                //Log.e(TAG, "pixel"+i +pixels[i]);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To set the colors of the pixels in your `pixels` array, get values from the static methods of Android's [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class and assign them into your array. When you're done, use `setPixels` to copy the pixels back to the bitmap.

For example, to turn the first five rows of the bitmap blue:

```java
import android.graphics.Color;

int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
for (int i=0; i<myBitmap.getWidth()*5; i++)
    pixels[i] = Color.BLUE;
myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

You can also set a pixel's color in a Bitmap object one at a time without having to set up a pixel buffer with the setPixel() method:

```java
myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(45, 127, 0));
```

Comment: how to do this to get all pixels

Comment: @Sheychan  if I does not get you wrong, BHSPitMonkey created a empty pixels array with size equal to total number of pixels first. Then  myBitmap is some bitmap you obtained from drawable to bitmap.  this myBitmap.getPixels  first parameter pixels is the array we just created and then finally this pixels array will be updated with colors of what myBitmap store.