# Change pixels in bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel

I want to change pixels of my bitmap dynamically, but it is not mutable, so it return an IllegalStateException.

Here my code :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
int[] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth()*bm.getHeight()]; 
 bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
```

// ...work on pixels...

```
bm.setPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the color of certain pixels in bitmap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916216/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-pixels-in-bitmap-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, to turn the first four rows of the bitmap blue:

```
import android.graphics.Color;

int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
for (int i=0; i<myBitmap.getWidth()*4; i++)
    pixels[i] = Color.BLUE;
myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

You can also set a pixel's color in a Bitmap object one at a time without having to set up a pixel buffer with the setPixel() method:

```
myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(45, 127, 0));
```

Use below method to get Mutable Bitmap from Resources

```
    public static Bitmap getMutableBitmap(Resources resources,int resId) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId, options);
}
```

or use

```
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

to get mutable Bitmap from immutable bitmap.

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of bitmap pixels?