# ColorMatrixColorFilter to invert alpha?

Tags: android, alpha, colormatrix

My initial drawable has the properties that every pixel is either black or transparent.

I want to apply a filter that turns all the black pixels transparent, and all the transparent pixels white.

I'm having trouble figuring out the math to generate the proper [matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html).

Comment: if it is just as simple as changing each black pixel to transparent pixel then you can just get all the pixel of the drawable and iterate and change the pexil depending on the target color, Complexity would be `O(N)`. you can go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916216/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-pixels-in-bitmap-android

Comment: Well, that does some like a reasonable approach.