# How to change the color of a specific pixel of an image in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to Android and am doing my own mini-project and I want to change a specific pixel's color. searching for how to do so, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916216/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-pixels-in-bitmap-android) question from a couple of years back. I tried `myBitmap.setPixel(10, 10, Color.rgb(45, 127, 0));`, but when I am actually activating it on my phone, it just crashes the second I activate this line of code. It seems to crash whenever I'm interacting with the bitmap. `int x =myBitmap.getHeight();` this line also crashes the app.

Yet, the initial creation of the bitmap doesn't cause any problems:

```
background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dangeon);
background.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
background.buildDrawingCache(true);
dang = background.getDrawingCache();
```

Do I have to install any package or activate anything to use the setPixel or getHeight functions? Alternatively, is there any other way to change a specific pixel?

logcat error when trying @jayanth suggestion:

2021-10-09 20:23:18.276 24894-24894/Aviv.Aviv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: Aviv.Aviv, PID: 24894
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(android.graphics.Bitmap$Config, boolean)' on a null object reference
at Aviv.Aviv.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:247)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305)
at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7089)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying `setPixel()` method on the immutable bitmap. it will throw a `IllegalStateException`.

first, create a mutable copy of your bitmap. and then you can change the color of the pixel in your bitmap.

```
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
int red = 255; //replace it with your color
int green = 255; //replace it with your color
int blue = 255; //replace it with your color
int color = Color.argb(0xFF, red, green, blue);
mutableBitmap.setPixel(indexI, indexJ, color);
//now if you apply it to any image view to see change.
imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
```

Comment: the line `Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);` causes my phone to crash again @Jayanth

Comment: whats the error log?

Comment: how can I see an error log? all I know is that when I run this on my phone the app closes itself

Comment: you can see error log in logcat of android studio

Comment: didn't know such a thing exist. anyways:

Comment: please pate all the red lined logs

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(android.graphics.Bitmap$Config, boolean)' on a null object reference`
is the first line

Comment: ill edit the entire thing into the post as it is too long for here

Comment: are you using glide to load image to imageview

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
use this line get bitmap from imageview

Comment: since you are bitmap from imageview is null the above exception coming

Comment: I don't know what glide is... I gave it an id and used `background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dangeon);`

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); use this line get bitmap from imageview

Comment: `dang1 = ((BitmapDrawable)background.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` crash again

Comment: whats the error

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Aviv.Aviv/Aviv.Aviv.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference`
first line